# How to use a variable in an awk expression

Tags: string, bash, awk, printf

I'm trying to make this command:

```
sed bla bla filename | awk '{printf "%s %s_entry_%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f",$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

But the thing is, i want the %.3f part to be variable. So in one case it could be %.3f and in another it could be %.3f %.3f %.3f. So i'll just use a static one in my example code for clarity. So if i want 4 of these %.3f and put them in variable $values like so:

```
values="%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f"
```

Then how can I put this string in the awk expression, without making awk to just put literally "${values}" in there. The following is my non-working-attempt:

```
sed bla bla filename | awk '{printf "%s %s_entry_${values}",$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `-v` option of awk to pass in variable from the shell

```
#!/bin/bash    
awk -v values="${values}" '{gsub("blah","replace");printf "%s %s_entry_"values ....}' file
```

the `gsub()` function is to replace what you have with that `sed` command. So just one awk command will do. `sed` is redundant in this case (and most other cases where awk is used)

Comment: Thnx, just using awk -v values="${values}" worked like a charm! +1 and accept for you!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to use actual awk variables:

```
sed bla bla filename | awk -v values="$values" '{printf "%s %s_entry_"values,$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

Or with bash:

```
awk -v values="$values" '{printf "%s %s_entry_"values,$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' <(sed bla bla filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that `values` is a shell variable, then this will work:

```
sed bla bla filename | awk '{printf "%s %s_entry_"ENVIRON["values"],$1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

Comment: That only works if you `export values` or `values=something awk ...`

Comment: Or if you write `values=... awk '...'`. But still, good point.